# Microphone records audio only when it's called by one process

Tags: microphone

I am facing a problem where the microphone is recording audio only when it's called by one process. i.e.

I am having a java sound recording application it works fine when i execute it.

Now i am running a flash application where the flash application also uses microphone object.

Once again i am running the same java recording application. but this time it's throwing line not available exception. 
Recording is working fine in windows and MAC

Answer (score 1):

You might need to install the pulseaudio utilities to manually configure them

`sudo apt-get install paman padevchooser paprefs pavucontrol pavumeter`

Once that's done, fire up `pavucontrol` and take a look at the recording tab for details. It's possible you might have muted it on accident. 
[image]